# Why is implicitly declaring functions problematic?

Tags: functions, declarations

I believe one used to be able to do this in C:

```c
int main(void) {
    return printf("Hello world!") > 0;
}
```

Now this became invalid in C99, and one must do this:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // int printf(const char *restrict, ...);
int main(void) {
    return printf("Hello world!") > 0;
}
```

What are/were the perceived problems with supporting implicit declaration of functions in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be a design space where implicit function declarations are desirable, such as when synthesising functions from structural effect handlers or struct fields, however C's approach is problematic for a simple reason: it assumes an unknown function to be of type `int()` and to be `extern`.
This means it works with `printf`, but not with `malloc`, nor `atof`.
It did make *some* sense for such a feature to exist in early C, as almost all routines from its stdlib returned either `void` or `int`, and as `()` makes a function variadic, however, for C99 the Committee decided to remove implicit declarations, justifying its action as so:

> 25 A new feature of C99: The rule for implicit declaration of functions has been removed in C99.
> The effect is to guarantee the production of a diagnostic that will catch an additional category of
> programming errors. After issuing the diagnostic, an implementation may choose to assume an
> implicit declaration and continue translation in order to support existing programs that exploited
> this feature.

- [Rationale for International Standard Programming Languages C Revision 5.10 April-2003§6.5.2.2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

## Typos

Consider this code:

```c
int main(void) {
  return pritnf("Hello, World!\n") > 0;
}
```

This file would compile, and only fail at link-time when `pritnf` can’t be found. Speaking from experience, linker errors are a lot harder to diagnose than compiler errors, since they don’t point to a location in the original source code.

Answer (score 5):

To compile a call to a function, it is crucial to know its signature precisely. If it is left to be inferred from the argument types, it allows for hard-to-trace mistakes (like wrong argument order, or assumed implicit casts not taking place)